# forward:/ for Zuul route not working with SPA/Angular

Tags: java, spring, angular, spring-boot, netflix-zuul

I have an API-Gateway for one API and the UI configured.

```
zuul:
    ignored-patterns: /health
    routes:
        fbresource:
            path: /fb/**
            url: http://localhost:8081/
        angularresource:
            path: /**
            url: http://localhost:4200/bpproxy/
```

Locally everthing is fine, but for centralized development, this is going to be deployed via openshift and the angular part is being compiled and put into the static dir.

For this we overwrite the angularresource part like:

```
angularresource:
    path: /**
    url: forward:/
```

If we load http://example.com/bpproxy/ angular is loading, but if I try to get directly via URL to a component ( http://examplel.com/bpproxy/welcome) it says:

```
2018-01-24 11:18:07.195 ERROR 10236 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter : Cannot forward to error page for request [/welcome] as the response has already been committed. As a result, the response may have the wrong status code. If your application is running on WebSphere Application Server you may be able to resolve this problem by setting com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.invokeFlushAfterService to false
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Change config to:

```
angularresource:
    path: /asd
    url: http://localhost:4200/bpproxy/
```

Route now does not match and Spring delivers static content.